# Story featuring a spaceship computer falling in love with the crew

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember that the crew was 3 men. The ship computer falls in love after one of them reads his bad poetry to her, and decides to ‘elope’ with them. Then, after successfully pissing her off, she lands on a post-apocalypse inhabitable planet, has an affair with the planets’ dead civilisations’ security system… but then, at the end, bad poetry saves the day.

Does anybody know the title/author?

Comment: Sounds like an episode of Futurama.

Comment: It was very tongue-in-cheek! But it was was reprinted in one of the sf anthologies (probably 70's or 80's).... Although I can imagine Fry writing bad poetry, that would lead a crazy computer to fall in love with him.....One more thing I remember is that one of the crewmen theorised that the computers' AI was composed out of old women's brains....so....now it kinda sounds like an episode of Red Dwarf, hehe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it - it's ["Lulu"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45965) (1957) by Clifford D Simak. I read it in "Best Science Fiction Stories of Clifford D. Simak"